# Rotate view in simulator doesn't work

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad, ios4, rotation

In UIViewController implementation i overriden shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation method and return YES (or TRUE). Also i overriden this method:

```
-(void) willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
    image.frame = CGRectMake(448, 381, 128, 113);
    progresView.frame = CGRectMake(448, 498, 130, 11);
    activityIndicator.frame = CGRectMake(448, 514, 20, 20);
    statusLabel.frame = CGRectMake(473, 534, 97, 18);


} else {
    image.frame = CGRectMake(335, 643, 128, 113);
    progresView.frame = CGRectMake(335, 760, 130, 11);
    activityIndicator.frame = CGRectMake(335, 776, 20, 20);
    statusLabel.frame = CGRectMake(360, 776, 97, 18);

}
```

}

But when i play application in simulator or device, rotate doesn't work. It shows only in portrait mode. What am I doing wrong? any ideas?

P.S. I Am using XCode 4.0.2 and application is for iPad

Comment: I just wanted to note that you can use the UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape macro instead of checking for LandscapLeft and LandscapeRight yourself. 

[UIKit Function Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html)

Answer (score 0):

You mean in UIViewController... not UIView right? Those methods are in the controller not at the view level....

Comment: also, everything after "else" works fine, so method is good. The thing is that it works only in portrait mode. It doesn't work in portraitUpsideDown, landscape left/right modes

Comment: IS this the top level view controller?

Comment: So if you have a view controller that has another view controller as a subview then the first one will receive the shouldRotate methods and will need to pass that on to it's children. If using a UINavigationController etc, they handle this for you...

Comment: it's maybe problem in launch image, cause xcode keep telling me, that it's size is does not mach recomemmended size, while it does. This view comes after launch image and launch image also works only in portrait (i don't know why). All other views after this view works just fine

Comment: Parent of this view controller is in app delegate: [self.window addSubview:syncView.view];    syncView is that view which doesn't rotate

Comment: Can you paste the code you have for shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation, and confirm that it gets called?

Comment: - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{    
    return TRUE;
    
}

Comment: It gets called, i cheched it with logs. Actually it is called 3 times :D

Comment: I checked that this method -(void) willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {} isn't called at all, even it has to